# Session Failover in JBoss/WildFly

Tags: session, wildfly, session-replication

## Setup:

- Two Linux machines
- Start Server in standalone mode
- configuration used is standalone-full-ha.xml
- cluster-demo.war deployed to both nodes with  tag

Cluster successfully formed between the two nodes. I can see the jgroups messages and having their cluster views updated correctly.

## Scenario:

> - Call `node1/cluster-demo/put.jsp`
> - Call `node1/cluster-demo/get.jsp` (Session lives)
> - Restart node1. Session persists
> - **Call `node2/cluster-demo/get.jsp`**
> - **Session is null (why?)**

```
     <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:3.0">
        <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server" aliases="singleton cluster">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <distributed-cache name="default" mode="SYNC">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <distributed-cache name="dist" mode="ASYNC" owners="2" l1-lifespan="0">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store/>
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <distributed-cache name="dist" mode="ASYNC" owners="2" l1-lifespan="0">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store/>
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </invalidation-cache>
            <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC"/>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Hi, @BasitAnwer, have you solved this problem?

Comment: I remember i solved it but forgot how i did it. Sorry